# A design with or without shapeless for cross dependency in Scala?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have two package that I want to make them as independent as possible.First package UTIL and package USER.
UTIL will most of the data-structures that I need and USER will be another package that has some local classes. I have to write class A in USER package which also I need to have some instance of it in UTIL package. So I wrote an interface "IA" in UTIL package and implemented it in USER (A extends IA).
the problem is I have to check the "instance of" IA everywhere in my code to use it (boilerplate).
What would be the best design in this situation let's say using "shapeless" or any other existing mechanism. 
Edited:
adding example:

```
package UTIL
trait IA
case class B(value:List[IA])

package USER
case class A extends IA
```

then in my code I have something like this:

```
val b = B(List(A()))
//if I want to access to b.value
b.value foreach(element => element match{
case A => ??? 
case .....
})
```

Is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but it doesn't sound like you need Shapeless.

Comment: @TravisBrown thanks for reply, what would be your suggestion then?

Comment: I'd need a more concrete example (sorry).

Comment: @TravisBrown updated with an example

Comment: `b.value` will never match `A`.

Comment: @Ryan you are right, I also don't know to write the pattern match here, let's say I checked the instanceOf it every time. what I meant was that I always should use some extra coding to get the thing. can shapeless or other design helps me?

Comment: That will still never match `A`.  `b.value` will always be a `List[IA]`.  I don't see why you're bringing pattern matching into this unless you're trying to deconstruct the list.

Comment: @Ryan let's say I don't use pattern-match and I do something like if(element.getClass == A.getClass) ...; my main question is: is there any better way to construct the list or define my classes that help me avoiding boilerplate?